# How to return list of booleans to see if elements of one list in another list

Tags: python, list, matching

I have two lists:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
B = [2,3,4]
```

and want to get a boolean list of length(A) where the element at each index indicates whether the element at the same index in A is in anywhere in the list B. The return value would be:

```
[False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

It would be easy to write a function, but want to know if there is a paradigmatic way of doing it in Python.

In R, the counterpart would be

```
which(A %in% b)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use a list comprehension:

```
In [164]: A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

In [165]: B = [2,3,4]

In [166]: [x in B for x in A]
Out[166]: [False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

If `B` is huge then better convert it to a `set` first. As, membership test for sets is `O(1)`
compared to `O(n)` in lists.

```
In [167]: b=set(B)

In [168]: [x in b for x in A]
Out[168]: [False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [1]: A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

In [2]: B = [2,3,4]

In [3]: map(B.__contains__, A)
Out[3]: [False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: Ah this is really good, though is map() a direct equivalent of a list comprehension?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to write it (but slower due to lambda usage):

```
>>> A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> B = [2,3,4]
>>> S = set(B)
>>> map(lambda x: x in S, A)
[False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: List comprehensions are converted to an implicit loop just like the map call, so I see no reason why your version should be faster. Also there's the lambda overhead as mentioned by Ashwini. A quick test on my machine showed that your solution is actually way slower, about 25% for a lengths of 50k/1M for A and B, and about 100% for lengths 500k/10M.

Comment: @l4mpi: Since I have added this answer, Ashwini has edited his one. Originally, he didn't mention set conversion (that was the improvement I suggested). I agree with your microbenchmark, just did the same.

Comment: Damn these stealth edits, I even checked the post times before commenting :P (I find this behaviour of hiding edits really confusing, but apparently meta thinks it's great...)

Comment: To be fair I didn't even saw your solution, I had this `set` based solution in mind as soon as I saw the question. A +1 anyway.