# How can I mark 1/0 at index in a list with reference to another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have an ordered list for reference (in the example of length 10):

`ref = ["tom", "was", "playing", "ball", "in", "the", "garden", "with", "his", "friends"]`

And I have a list of 3 items:

`words = ["ball", "garden", "friends"]`

I want to convert the above `ref` list to a list of ones and zeros like so.. If `t` is in the sequence of strings, we should put a `1` at the i-th position of the output vector, otherwise it should be `0`:

#### Output:

`[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]`

Can I do this using a one liner?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I understand I need to rephrase my question with better language, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I couldn't find answers to my question and hence asked it on SO. I have got my answer

Comment: Which part exactly did you have difficulty with? This question is too broad.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have described the problem I was facing in the description. You could help me rephrase the question title

Comment: Also, see [How to return list of booleans to see if elements of one list in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14430454/7851470)

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension and check with `in` as following:

```
ref = ["tom", "was", "playing", "ball", "in", "the", "garden", "with", "his", "friends"]

words = ["ball", "garden", "friends"]

output = [1 if r in words else 0 for r in ref]

print(output)
```

Here's the working repl.it project: https://repl.it/@HarunYlmaz/PepperyShamefulCodewarrior

Comment: Thanks! I was working with TFIDF vectors and got confused for a bit.