# How do you output boolean if column containing lists have elements from another larger list?

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a column where each row contains a list of strings of varying lengths. I need to create a new column that has a list of booleans (equivalent to the original list) of whether or not each element is found in ANOTHER (larger) list.

This is what I am doing and well, it clearly does not work. I based it off of this question:
[How to return list of booleans to see if elements of one list in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430454/how-to-return-list-of-booleans-to-see-if-elements-of-one-list-in-another-list)

```
data = [
    [1, ["cat", "cat", "mouse"]],
    [2, ["dog", "horse"]],
    [3, ["cat"]],
    [
        4,
        np.nan,
    ],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", "list"])
df

main_list = ["cat", "dog", "mouse", "pig", "cow"]

df["contains_item_from_list"] = df["list"].apply(
    (lambda x: [x in main_list for x in b])
)
```

[image]

desired output:

```
ID     list          contains_item_from_list
1  [cat,cat,mouse]      [True, True, True]
2  [dog,horse]          [True, False]
3  [cat]                [True]
4   NaN                 [False]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also apply a function that iterates over each list in `list`. This should be faster than exploding the column:

```
main_set = set(main_list)
df["contains_item_from_list"] = df['list'].apply(lambda x: [w in main_set for w in x] if isinstance(x, list) else [x in main_set])
```

Output:

```
   ID               list contains_item_from_list
0   1  [cat, cat, mouse]      [True, True, True]
1   2       [dog, horse]           [True, False]
2   3              [cat]                  [True]
3   4                NaN                 [False]
```

Answer (score 3):

`explode` flattens all the lists in a Series, but items that were in the same list all share the same index that the list they came from did, so after you use `isin` to check which items of `main_list` are in the Series, you can use `groupby` with `level=0` to group by the 0th (first) level of the index, and then convert them back to lists:

```
df['contains_item_from_list'] = df['list'].explode().isin(main_list).groupby(level=0).apply(list)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
0    [True, True, True]
1         [True, False]
2                [True]
3               [False]
Name: list, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `explode` then `isin`

```
df['new'] = df['list'].explode().isin(main_list).groupby(level=0).any()
df
Out[130]: 
   ID               list    new
0   1  [cat, cat, mouse]   True
1   2       [dog, horse]   True
2   3              [cat]   True
3   4                NaN  False
```

Update

```
df['new'] = df['list'].explode().isin(main_list).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
df
Out[132]: 
   ID               list                 new
0   1  [cat, cat, mouse]  [True, True, True]
1   2       [dog, horse]       [True, False]
2   3              [cat]              [True]
3   4                NaN             [False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension, easy and faster

```
df["contains_item_from_list"]= df['list'].fillna('xx').apply(lambda x: [val in main_list for val in x])

    ID            list     contains_item_from_list
0   1  [cat, cat, mouse]      [True, True, True]
1   2       [dog, horse]           [True, False]
2   3              [cat]                  [True]
3   4                NaN                  [False]
```