# Check if element exist in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm new to python. I have two lists. The first one is `ipaddress= [['10.25.16.201'], ['10.25.16.202'], ['10.25.16.203'], ['10.90.90.10']]` and the second one is `newipaddress =[["10.110.34.50"], ["10.25.17.212"], ["10.90.90.10"]]`

How can I check `ipaddress` to verify if it contains an element from `newipaddress`? This is what I've tried. Thanks in advance!

```
for x in ipAddress:
    print(x)
    for y in newipaddress:
        print(y)
        if (y in x):
            print(y)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return list of booleans to see if elements of one list in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430454/how-to-return-list-of-booleans-to-see-if-elements-of-one-list-in-another-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can avoid loops altogether and instead use a list comprehension:

```py
ipaddress = [['10.25.16.201'], ['10.25.16.202'], ['10.25.16.203'], ['10.90.90.10']]
newipaddress = [["10.110.34.50"], ["10.25.17.212"], ["10.90.90.10"]]
output = [x in newipaddress for x in ipaddress]
print(output)  # [False, False, False, True]
```

To display the element in the first list, if it exist in the second list, use:

```py
output = [x for x in ipaddress if x in newipaddress]
print(output)  # [['10.90.90.10']]
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I display that element instead of displaying  [False, False, False, True]?

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'if x in' to accomplish what you're after:

```
for x in ipaddress:
    if x in newipaddress:
        print('ip in newipaddress:', x)
```